# htaccess not applying rewriting rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite a url from:

`https://www.example.com/project6-home`  -> `https://www.example.com/project6/home`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/project6-home$"  "/project6/home" [PT]
</IfModule>
```

Its not working and unfortunately there is no console.log() :-(

Comment: @anubhava No, that didn't help at all. Do you think its problem because I am on localhost?

Comment: @anubhava Yes its working, showing error 500. But maybe I misunderstood what RewriteRule should do. I want the user to see in the address bar the following "https//:www.example.com/project6/home"

Comment: _Aside:_ "`https//:www.example.com`" - the colon goes after the protocol... `https://www`, not before the hostname. (I thought this was just a typo, but you are repeatedly referring to this incorrectly?)

Comment: Or, maybe you mean "redirect", not "rewrite"?

Comment: @MrWhite Sorry, its a typo. I don't want redirect. I want a pretty url.

Comment: @anubhava Unfortunately, its not working. Doesn't it require quotes around the arguments?

Comment: What URL are you requesting? ie. What URL are you linking to? What is the filesystem path that handles the request? (You don't need quotes unless you have _spaces_ in the argument.)

Comment: @MrWhite URL that is pointing to the file is https://www.example.com/project6-home. I want users to see https://www.example.com/project6/home in their address bar.

Comment: That's the problem, if you want users to "see" `/project6/home` then you need to physically link to that URL. You then internally rewrite to the underlying filesystem path that handles the URL. Otherwise, you would need to _externally redirect_ the user to that URL.

Comment: @anubhava Its a .php file using wordpress

Comment: @MrWhite Unfortunately, I am not able to create that file structure in Wordpress. That sucks, thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah, it's WordPress... you should be creating routes inside WP - this isn't something you should be doing (or even can do) in `.htaccess`.

Comment: @MrWhite Its simple to do with with post types in Wordpress using premalinks. However, I am using "pages" and so I don't really understand it and there is no good answer on the net. I have been searching for the past 5 hours. :-(. Even asked a question on stack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64171618/how-to-change-permalinks-for-pages-not-blog-posts